# How to show custom cart_item_data on Woocommerce cart page?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to add a product to the Woocommerce cart with some custom additional data. I think the addition to the cart works well since two lines of the same product are shown on the cart page. However, I would like it to be visible on the cart like on the following picture:

[image: Additional info seen on cart page]

To add the product to the cart I use the following code:

```
WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id, $quantity );
```

And the following filter is added to the `woocommerce_add_cart_item_data` to make sure the 'emaill' value is added to the cart item:

```
function plugin_add_cart_item_data( $cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id ) {
  if( isset( $_POST['emaill'] ) ) {
    $cart_item_data['emaill'] = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['emaill'] );
  }
  return $cart_item_data;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'plugin_add_cart_item_data', 10, 3 );
```

To see the extra 'emaill' info like in the picture above, I added the following code:

```
function plugin_republic_get_item_data( $item_data, $cart_item_data ) {
  if( isset( $cart_item_data['emaill'] ) ) {
    $item_data[] = array(
    'key' => __( 'Your name', 'plugin-republic' ),
    'value' => wc_clean( $cart_item_data['emaill'] ));
  }
  return $item_data;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'plugin_republic_get_item_data', 10, 2 );
```

But the products are just shown as this; no 'emaill' value shown here:

[image: cart]

My question is: have I done something wrong? Is it possible that there is a conflict with my theme (Bricks), which just ignores this 'email' value? If yes, where should I search for the cause?

How can I properly debug this? In which DB table can I take a look to see whether the actual 'emaill' value is stored? Can I $cart_item_data the info in the console or something?

BTW, the 'emaill' info is also not shown in the admin dashboard, but I guess that's caused by the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of potential problems. Here's how I would start to debug it:

0. I know stupid right, but you're trying to do 'emaill' and not 'email' on purpose, right?
1. Make sure that the 'emaill' field is actually being sent through the POST request when adding the product to the cart. You can inspect the network request in chrome dev tools.
2. add error_log() statements inside your filter functions (plugin_add_cart_item_data() and plugin_republic_get_item_data()) to check if they are being executed properly. For example:

   ```
    function plugin_add_cart_item_data( $cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id ) {
    error_log('plugin_add_cart_item_data function called');
    if( isset( $_POST['emaill'] ) ) {
        $cart_item_data['emaill'] = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['emaill'] );
    }
    return $cart_item_data;
   ```

   }

Comment: 0) Yes, on purpose 1) The field is actually sent in the post script 2) I have added them, but I do not know where to look for the logs. Please send me the location where I could find them 3) I do not have the 'wp_woocommerce_cart_contents' table. I do have other woocommerce_... and wc_... tables, but none of them seems to contain info about cart

Comment: The location of the error log will depend on how you are hosting the site. Usually it's stored in /var/log/apache2 or something similar. If you are running via cPanel it will be in there. How are you hosting the site?

Comment: I have Siteground hosting

Comment: yourwebsite.com/public_html/wp-content/debug.log

Comment: Its also not located on that spot..

Comment: https://www.siteground.com/kb/wordpress-logs/#:~:text=SiteGround%20users%20can%20view%20the,your%20website%20in%20chronological%20order.

Comment: Okay, I have found the correct log file. The weird thing is that there are no logs when getting the cart item data. It seems like that `woocommerce_get_item_data` filter is not called... Do you have an idea why it is not called?